Connect PowerBI to MySQL over HTTPS
I want to connect PowerBI (desktop) to a remote MySQL database. I installed the MySQL Connector and I was able to connect PowerBI to MySQL database, using the server IPs (and port 3306).
However, in the this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/mysql-database I see in the screenshots that the connection string they use is something like https://mysql.contoso.com/... (so it's using the HTTPS protocol).
I am wondering how this works? Does it really tunnel MySQL protocol over a HTTPS (i.e. data goes over port 443 with HTTP headers) or is it just retrieving the database connection from a HTTPS request and then uses MySQL protocol directly (i.e. data goes over port 3306)? If it's the former case, then how can I set this up?

No, mysql connector and mysql do not support http connections. Database name is also starnge. I would raise this question on MS product support forum as it is not programming related question.
